# Converting SQL syntax dashboard widgets to CDK

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I'm trying to convert some old dashboard widgets into CDK. The widgets are all referencing custom metrics being output by the service, and performing some basic SQL-style grouping and filtering by various dimensions on the metric. The issue is I can't figure out what the syntax for adding such a widget looks like, and haven't been able to find references to SQL syntax in the AWS documentation; there are references to SEARCH expressions, but those seem to be for discovering metrics from cloudwatch logs, and references to MATH expressions, but none for these SQL queries I'm seeing.

How do I add a metric like the below to a cloudwatch widget?

```
"metrics": [
[ { "expression": "SELECT Count(outputRate) from ExampleService GROUP BY ProcessKey", "label exampleMetric", "id": "q1", "region": "us-east-1"} ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel foolish for saying this, but as it turns out, MathExpressions are actually capable of running SQL-style aggregation and filtering. It simply doesn't appear to be documented, perhaps under the assumption that it was obvious.